# html echo a quote around a variable

Tags: html, variables, echo, quotes

I am using *html* to get one directory to echo its data to another directory.  `tt` is a time string

```
 foreach tt ($tts)
 echo "<option value=${tt}>${tt}</option>"
 end
```

This produces the following code in the new directory

```
<option value=2012072612>2012072612</option>
<option value=2012072606>2012072606</option>
<option value=2012072512>2012072512</option>
```

My goal is to get it to have double quotations around the first instance of the variable, like below.  What do I need to do?

```
<option value="2012072512">2012072512</option>
<option value="2012072412">2012072412</option>
<option value="2012072406">2012072406</option>
```

Comment: what server side language are you using?

Comment: Actually, I'm probably not using php, given that the backslash escape key does not work.  Sorry for the ignorance; I am rather new to this.

Comment: What extension are you adding to the file you are editing in? Not .html I presume?

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the double quotes like this:

```
echo "<option value=\"${tt}\">${tt}</option>"
```

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me.  When I use the escpae quotes, the new directory does not display any of what I am attempting to echo.

Comment: @AlexKowaleski An alternative is to use single quotes around your value. They're just as valid.

Comment: I think the curly braces may be causing a syntax error. The `$` should be inside them, not outside. Or just remove them, since they're not necessary for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you everyone, but it turns out I don't need the quotes.  Really appreciate the help, though.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to move the { to the left of $ and add quotes

```
echo "<option value=\"{$tt}\">{$tt}</option>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language, there is an escape character that allows you to output something that ordinarily would be syntax or used by the compiler for something else. As you know, double quotes are used to denote strings, therefore just throwing them into your code wont work, so what you need to do is use the escape character of whatever language it is you are using.

For example, if you're using PHP, it would be

`echo "<option value=\"${tt}\">${tt}</option>"`

It may be worth it to note, that \ is the escape character in PHP, so what if you wanted to use a \ in your code because it's a directory or something like that? You use \ instead, to say "Escape the escape". You do this for anything that the compiler would return as a special symbol that you want to use. For example, \', \", \ are some of the bigger ones you'll see, so you can output ', " and \ symbols inside blocks of PHP. Most languages have an escape character, it's simply a matter of finding what one yours uses.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, this would work. I think the other one isn't working because it's calling the function within the echo as if the function was just any given text. This should do it. I think the single quotes will work. I'm pretty sure you need a semi colon at the end of echo (which I added) could be wrong though.

```
    foreach tt ($tts)
 echo '<option value="'.${tt}.'">'.${tt}.'</option>';
 end
```

or this way with double quotations....

```
echo "<option value=\"" .${tt}. "\">" .${tt}. "</option>";
```